# jmeter: Structuring a project

Tags: jmeter

I am looking for some advice on JMeter project structure. My case is the following:

I have quite a few separate tests for a related feature. For example:

1. Uploading images - seeing how many images can be uploaded in parallel
2. Seeing uploaded images - same as above
3. ....

I am trying to understand how to structure the code. From one side, it might be better to group all related features under the same TestPlan (one jmx file). However, in this case, it's not quite clear how to execute them in a way they don't interfere with each other. E.g., should I use this one thread-group after another option?

Alternatively, I can probably place every of the scenarios above into a separate JMX file, however, it feels like quite a bit of extra work (e.g. it seems to be a good idea to avoid one thread group per test plan type of setup)

Answer (score 0):

If Thread Groups are not connected, to wit there are some images in the system under test which can be "viewed" - then just go for 2 separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

In case you first need to upload the "image" and only then to "view" it - you can again use 2 separate Thread Groups and configure JMeter to run them consecutively on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

[image]

In general well-behaved JMeter test plan should represent real-life usage of your system so I think you should rather inspect [access logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging_(computing)) of the live system or reach out to business analysts to get understanding of the potential use cases and percentage of users who will upload and view the images.

Different Thread Groups should represent different groups of business users, if there is one group which performs different actions with various percentage probabilities you can go for a single Thread Group and distribute the test scenarios in it using [Throughout Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter), whatever is reflecting your test scenario and/or the easiest to implement.